# How to make linear-gradient background in React-native

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

How to crate gradient inside

```
<View />
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using expo,
i had created a separate component

you can import it in any component and use it

```js
import { fonts } from '@src/theme/typography'
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient'
import React from 'react'
import { ViewStyle, StyleProp, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native'


const Button = (props) => {
    const { style, text } = props
    return(
        <LinearGradient 
        colors={['#ffa700', '#ff9300']}
        style={[styles.container, style]}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
        {text}
        </Text>
        </LinearGradient>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: 48,
        borderRadius: 8
    },
    text: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginTop: 'auto',
        marginBottom: 'auto',
        color: '#fefffe',
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: fonts.medium,

    }
})

export default Button
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LinearGradient instead of a View and put your content in there.

```
  <LinearGradient
    colors={['#373B44', '#4286f4', '#373B44']}
    style={{
      flex: 1,
    }}
  >
    <Text>
      Test
    </Text>
  </LinearGradient>
```

But also you can use View as a content in the LinearGradient.

```
  <LinearGradient
    colors={['#373B44', '#4286f4', '#373B44']}
    style={{
      flex: 1,
    }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        margin: 20,
      }}
    >
      <Text>
        Test
      </Text>
    </View>
  </LinearGradient>
```

I also explained usage of react-native-linear-gradient and its features [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aztfJAbmXig) with source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this steps :

1) import `LinearGradient` from `react-native-linear-gradient` library.

```
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
```

2) set some flex value to `LinearGradient`

```
<LinearGradient
    colors={['#33ccff', '#ff99cc']}
    style={{ flex:1 }}
>
    <View>
        //set your content or elements here
    </View>
</LinearGradient>
```